# Why is my embedded & responsive video not responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-video, embedding

I have a video that is meant to appear in all screen sizes (except xs) over 4 columns. The code below isn't responsive, displaying the video VERY large. Tearing my hair out, need help!

```
<div class="hidden-xs col-sm-4 embed-responsive-16by9">
  <video class="embed-responsive-item" title="Former Balmain Massage therapist Blaise Bowling shows the ins and outs of pregnancy massage" poster="../../images/blaises_pregnancy_poster.jpg" controls  src="../../video/pregnancy360.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

The original video is barely 360px wide and it's rendered far too big... The page is at https://balmainmassage.com.au/2015/modalities/pregnancy.html

Thanks

Claudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `html`, I assume you have this in your `<head>` :

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
```

You should put your video in a `<div>` something like this:

```
<div class="responsive_video">                              
<video src="yourfolder/yourvideo.mp4" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" </video>     
</div>
```

Then, you should have this under your `@media only screen and (max-width : 960px)` in the bottom of your `css`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 960px) {

    .responsive_video video{
        width:100%;
                }
}
```